# Finding minimax estimator $\theta$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, minimax

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a random sample from $N(\theta,1)$  so that $\theta\geq a$ .

How can I calculate minimax estimator $\theta$ under loss function $L(\delta,\theta)=(\delta-\theta)^2$